# Display the input of QLineEdit in a different window and or dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am writing a small QT gui application where there is a QLineEdit in my mainwindow.ui and I want to display the entered text in a separate dialog and or window when a button is pressed.

Now, I have stored the input in a variable, and I am also able to show this string on a label within this same mainwindow,

```
void MainWindow::on_GoButton_clicked()
{
    QString mytext = ui->lineEdit_1->text();
    ui->label_1->setText(mytext);
}
```

Now, I want to open a popup dialog (can be a window also), for example SecDialog;

```
SecDialog secdialog;
secdialog.setModal(true);
secdialog.exec();
```

and display the text of mainwindow->mytext string variable in a label of the SecDialog. How can I do that ??? I know it is a basic level question, but I think it will help clear lot of my doubts reagrding moving values of variables in between forms and classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Situation

So this is your situation:

[image]

From your code, the dialog is a [**modal dialog**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs):

```
SecDialog secdialog;
//secdialog.setModal(true); // It's not needed since you already called exec(), and the 
                            // dialog will be automatically set to be modal just like what
                            // document says in Chernobyl's answer 

secdialog.exec();
```

---

## Solution

**To make the dialog display the text from the Window,**

> the concept is to **pass** the information(text) from the Window
>   to the dialog, and use a **setter function** from the dialog to display it.

Like **Floris Velleman**'s answer, he passed the `mytext` string (by reference) to a customized dialog constructor and called the setter `theStringInThisClass(myString)` at once.

The implementation detail of this function is complemented by **Chernobyl**'s answer (use the name `setLabelText` instead):

```
void SecDialog::setLabelText(QString str)
{
    ui->label->setText(str); // this "ui" is the UI namespace of the dialog itself.
                             // If you create the dialog by designer, it's from dialog.ui
                             // Do not confuse with the ui from mainwindow.ui
}
```

**Chernobyl** suggested another way which calls the setter in the slot function and it bypasses the need of defining another constructor, but basically the concept is the same:

```
void MainWindow::on_GoButton_clicked()
{
    QString mytext = ui->lineEdit_1->text();
    ui->label_1->setText(mytext);
    SecDialog secdialog;

    secdialog.setLabelText(myText); // display the text in dialog

    secdialog.exec();
}
```

---

## Comment

I try to illustrate the concept as clear as possible, because from my previous experience on your question, you just **"copy & paste"** codes from answers and took them as your final solution, which is not right. So I hope this summary could help you understand the concept and then you may **write your own code**.

Comment: I thought that our answers was informative enough, but you did great job and show our answers in super graphical way, thank you, upvoted answer.

Comment: @Chernobyl Both of your answers are informative enough actually. But for OP's case, I noticed he just directly copy and paste the answer code most of time so I think an elaboration in detail might help him understand the solution better. It's case dependent : )

Comment: thanks tay2510 it really helped a lot. actually i am still in a learning phase and using bits and pieces of codes to build up small guis. thanks to chernobyl and floris velleman too..

Comment: I think this is a great visual representation! Passing the QString as `const QString&` in this case should be done for the setter as well (good practice) since you won't change its value.

Comment: I'd like to raise some awareness about using the `exec` function by providing [this](https://blogs.kde.org/2009/03/26/how-crash-almost-every-qtkde-application-and-how-fix-it-0) link. It can be quite risky to use it, especially in bigger applications.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SecDialog` is a custom class with an interface file as well you might want to pass it as a constructor argument or pass it by using another function.

So in the `SecDialog` constructor you could have something like:

```
SecDialog::SecDialog(QWidget* parent, const QString& myString)
    : QDialog(parent),
    theStringInThisClass(myString) 
{}
```

And then you could call it like:

```
SecDialog secdialog(this, mytext);
```

Comment: it is showing error, /home/aj/MY_QT_WORK/10_testing_lineedit_to_label/secdialog.cpp:4: error: prototype for ‘SecDialog::SecDialog(QWidget*, const QString&)’ does not match any in class ‘SecDialog’

Comment: Of course you have to update your dialog class definition according to the change as well if you want to use this approach

Comment: You would have to update the constructor of SecDailog to: `SecDialog(QWidget* parent, const QString& myString);`

Answer (score 1):

This task can be easy done with getter/setter method or with signal and slot, but setter is more suitable here. In SecDialog header:

```
public:
void setLabelText(QString str);
//in cpp 
void SecDialog::setLabelText(QString str)
{
    ui->label->setText(str);//it is label dialog
}
```

Usage:

```
secDialog.setLabelText(myText);
```

Also line where you set modal to true is not necessary because

> This property holds whether show() should pop up the dialog as modal
>   or modeless. By default, this property is false and show() pops up the
>   dialog as modeless. Setting his property to true is equivalent to
>   setting QWidget::windowModality to Qt::ApplicationModal. **exec()
>   ignores the value of this property and always pops up the dialog as
>   modal.**

Comment: it is showing 2 build issues; /home/aj/MY_QT_WORK/10_testing_lineedit_to_label/secdialog.h:16: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Ui::SecDialog’ and; /home/aj/MY_QT_WORK/10_testing_lineedit_to_label/secdialog.h:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct Ui::SecDialog’

Comment: I see that someone disagree with me, can you explain me what is wrong here please?

Comment: @AmarjitBiswas no, no, no, forgot about my comment, just check my edited answer. Problem is that code generated by uic included in cpp, so usage in header ui pointer has no sence.