# How to display the input of QLineEdit in a dialog on the label of mainwindow?

Tags: c++, dialog, qt-creator

I'm new to QtCreator and created a button on the mainwindow that opens a dialog. In the dialog i added QLineEdit and a button. When i click on this button, i want the input text to be displayed on a Qlabel in the mainwindow.

I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798741/display-the-input-of-qlineedit-in-a-different-window-and-or-dialog) which is basicly the same, but for me it has to work the other way around.

So In the header of MainWindow.h i have added to public:

```
void setLabelText(QString str);
```

I created the getter/setter function and added it to MainWindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::setLabelText(QString str)
{
    ui->label->setText(str);//it is label dialog

}
```

And in the windowdialog.cpp i have added under button click() slot:

```
void WindowDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
    MainWindow MainWindow;
    MainWindow.setLabelText(str);
}
```

It compiles without errors. Yet when i click on the button in the dialog, it won't print the results in the mainwindow... I have been trying to find another examples about how to do this, but couldn't really find one yet. So what am i missing? Or how do i make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use signals and slots for this. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

you would need to connect the signal to a slot by using this command

```
connect(dlg,&DialogWindow::transmit,this,&MainWindow::update);
```

anytime you want to call the update function you would just need to emit the signal.

```
emit transmit(ui->lineEdit->text());
```

I created a dialog window class in this example.

Dialog.h

```
    #ifndef DIALOGWINDOW_H
    #define DIALOGWINDOW_H

    #include <QDialog>

    QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
    namespace Ui { class Dialog;   }

    QT_END_NAMESPACE

    class DialogWindow : public QDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        DialogWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~DialogWindow();

    signals:
        void transmit(QString txt);

    private slots:


        void on_buttonBox_accepted();

    private:

        Ui::Dialog *ui;
    };

    #endif // DIALOGWINDOW_H
```

Dialog.cpp

```
    #include "dialog.h"
    #include "ui_dialog.h"

    DialogWindow::DialogWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QDialog(parent),
         ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {
         ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    DialogWindow::~DialogWindow()
    {

    }

    void DialogWindow::on_buttonBox_accepted()
    {
        emit transmit(ui->lineEdit->text());
    }
```

MainWindow.h

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include "dialog.h"

    QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
    namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
    QT_END_NAMESPACE

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();

    private slots:
        void on_pushButton_clicked();
        void update(QString txt);

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow   *ui;
        DialogWindow    *dlg;
    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        dlg = new DialogWindow(NULL);

        connect(dlg,&DialogWindow::transmit,this,&MainWindow::update);

    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }


    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        dlg->show();
    }

    void MainWindow::update(QString txt)
    {
        ui->label->setText(txt);
    }
```

Comment: Nice! Thanx for this solution! Need to play a little more to know how it exactly works.

Comment: Oke, tried to add a second QLineEdit to it, but i don't really understand how todo this.

Comment: You need another connect. And another slot if you want a different function. Have a read through the docs or watch some youtube videos about signals and slots.

Comment: After experimenting a bit with both solutions, i ended up using yours instead of the other. So i accepted your answer instead of the other. Btw docs for qt are to me, very unclear...

Answer (score 1):

In this line `MainWindow MainWindow;`, you create a **new** `MainWindow`, but you want to set the text on your existing `MainWindow`.

Instead you might want to pass a reference or pointer to the `MainWindow` to the dialog, once you create it.

If you pass your `MainWindow` as the parent of the QDialog, you could do it this way:

```
void WindowDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
    static_cast<MainWindow*>(parent())->setLabelText(str);
}
```

A safer version using [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
void WindowDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
    MainWindow* window = dynamic_cast<MainWindow*>(parent());
    if (!window) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Parent was not a MainWindow"};
    }
    window->setLabelText(str);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it causes a crash.

Comment: @ArjanPoortman Do you pass a pointer to the MainWindow as parent to the WindowDialog when you create it? `WindowDialog dialog(this);`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean? I`m new to c++,  so where exactly do i pass the pointer?

Comment: When you create the dialog, you probably call `new WindowDialog()` somewhere. You should call `new WindowDialog(this)`.

Comment: @ArjanPoortman Be careful casting pointers like this though. If you mess up and the parent is not a `MainWindow`, you invoke undefined behaviour!

Comment: @ArjanPoortman I added a safer version that at least throws an exception, if you messed up.